# Can I do more have javascript do two things at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange need. I would like to do the following in javascript:

1. when a function is called I want
   to change the color of a DIV and
   then 1/2 second later I would like
   to change it back
2. at the same time as (1) I would
   like to make an Ajax call. The call
   typically takes one second

In other words I would like step 1 and step 2 to start at the same time.

My knowledge of javascript is pretty basic. Is this kind of thing possible? How about if I use jQuery, would that make it easier?

Comment: It sounds like there might be a better way to accomplish your goal. Do you want #1 to be running for exactly half the time of #2? For the whole time? What is the relationship between the two in terms of your application logic?

Comment: If you want the div to change back to its original color after the AJAX call returns, change it's color back in the callback function of the AJAX request.

Comment: Could you rewrite please the could you text of please question as it does not seems to be seems english valid? or do? more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery and its function `queue`, to delay an action.

I forked wdm's version on jsFiddle, to change it to `queue` style, instead of `setTimeout`. In my own belief, this is a much cleaner and better way to achieve what you are looking for.

Here is the [forked Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pGcEg/2/)

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
$('#change').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#a')
        .css('background-color', 'blue')
        .delay(500)
        .queue(function(next){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
            next();
        });

    $.ajax({}); // do the ajax call here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I created the first part for you. It sets the color to blue, then back to red a half second later (500 ms).

You can then add the code for the ajax request where I have the comment. The color change and ajax call will begin at the same time when the function is called.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/H39XZ/1/

```
$('#change').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#a').css('background-color', 'blue');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#a').css('background-color', 'red');
    }, 500);

    // Insert ajax call here

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. I had tried similar myself but was not sure of the exact syntax of the function(). I have a question. When setting the timeout to 5000 it delays for around 5 seconds. When setting to 10 it still delays for what seems at least a second. Any ideas on why that is?

Comment: @Marife The times should be accurate. I set it to 10 ms and it was going so fast I couldn't see the change.

Answer (score 0):

The very purpose of AJAX is to make asynchronous calls. You could execute a function using the **`setTimeout()`** and **`setInterval()`** if you want them to execute at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

One important concept is that javascript is a single-thread thing. Only one thing really happen, no parallel tasks.

Here is a [nice tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth) to get this point in details.

Now that doesn't mean javascript execution seems single-threaded for the final user. You've got plenty of tools with asynchronous ajax calls and timer-based events (like jQuery queues used in animation things) that will make the javascript jobs interlayed. This means pieces of jobs will be done step after step, and for several graphical zones, so you'll get the final impression they're done in parallel.

This is why @Shef answer is right, as well as @anirudh4444 one.